# PHP: SOAP Webservice with JSON responce

Tags: php, json, web-services, soap

I am developing a `webservice` in `PHP` using `SOAP` and I have to return the response in `JSON` format. `Webservice` method is simple. It takes an `array` as input and should return `JSON` object. Registering the method in `webservice` is like this:

```
$server->register(
  'getProducts', 
  array('arr' => 'xsd:array'), 
  array('return' => 'xsd:json')
);
```

And I am doing this inside the method:

```
 $sql3 = "SELECT name, price from products WHERE status_id=$staus_id and cat_id=$cat_id";
 $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
 $row3 = mysqli_fetch_all($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $json = json_encode($row3);
 return $json;
```

Whereas on `client` side I am doing this to catch the object and echo it:

```
$response = $client->getProducts($param);
echo $response;
```

But When I run the `client` side `script`, it gives nothing (an empty `json` object):

When I change the return type of the method to `string` in `$server->register` and I return an actual string in the method, it works fine but it doesn't in case of `JSON` object. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here, since you did a json_encode on the server side, you must do a json_decode on the client side.

Change the code on the last line from:

```
 echo $json;
```

to

```
 echo json_decode($json);
```